# Pass JSON object in GET request: iOS

Tags: ios, swift, api, url

I want to add the `JSON` object in GET request with `URL`. Please refer below URL.

```
https://testdata.com/xyz/&form={"id":"12", "data": "3"}
```

I am getting `nil` while converting `String` to `URL`

```
let serviceUrl = URL(string: url)
```

Thanks in advance.

I was already tried below solution but unfortunately no luck.

- JSONSerialization.data
- converting to string with utf8
- removed whitespaces if any
- addingPercentEncoding with URL host allowed

Comment: You are discouraged from sending JSON in an URL. Why not `https://testdata.com/xyz?id=12&data=3` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended, to send a request body with `GET` request. `GET` request means to fetch all the resources/content that this URL has to offer. If they are parsing the GET body on server side, it's against the semantics. But if you really need to do it. Use Almofire. Here's a Sample Code.

```
let parameters : [String : Any] = [
  "id":"12",
  "data":"3"

]

func getContent(parameters: [String: Any]) {
    Alamofire.request("http://18.218.235.193:3000/user/securedtoken", method: 
               .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseObject {(response:
            DataResponse<YOUR RESPONSE MODEL HERE>) in
            let response =  response.result.value
            //Do Something (Success)



            }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, but i need to pass as i showed in the example url as we have already some piece of code working with that in customer side with the same and we cannot change the API. So please let me know if there is any way for to pass the JSON object in the URL itself.I tried this method also but nope.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Alamofire library. You can do what you want using following code snippet

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["form": ["id": 12, "data": 3]])
         .response { request, response, data, error in
              print(request)
              print(response)
              print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, but i need to pass as i showed in the example url as we have already some piece of code working with that in customer side with the same and we cannot change the API. So please let me know if there is any way for to pass the JSON object in the URL itself. I tried this method also but nope.

Comment: can we create url like above in post atleast?

Comment: I do not understand what you meant to create url in post because if you are using post you need to send parameters inside your body. I recommend you to read following article about REST APIs `https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/`

Comment: Hi  Atalay Asa, thankyou for the help. Now i am sending in the body of POST  API